# SES in AWS, don't send my email

Tags: amazon-web-services, jakarta-mail, amazon-ses

I have an account in SES, in aws, I can send email from my localhost, I have limits increase, but from my web, SES doesn't send emails.

Do I need configuration anything else, for web?

Comment: are you in sandbox mode? are the emails you are trying to send to verified?

Comment: What are you doing, and what errors are you experiencing? How have you configured your app to communicate with SES?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. The problem was that I have several freeMarker, and I depends of the locale I send a kind of freeMarker, my file ftl for english was wrong, and the locale of AWS always is EN_US, and I did not know.